# How do I actually use the encrypted travis variable

Tags: bash, encryption, travis-ci

I have successfully encrypted my variable with travis using, `travis encrypt "secret_token" --add`, I see it on the .travis.yml

Now I would like to use this encrypted variable in a bash script like so, `firebase deploy --only functions --token="What goes here?"`

How do I actually use my newly encrypted travis variable?

Looks like you can also encrypt with this, `travis encrypt --pro secretKey="secretVar" --add`

Either way, how do I actually use this variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in bash it's

`firebase deploy --only functions --token=$secretKey`